# How to increase balun impedance ratio

Tags: balun

I have a balanced balun with 1:1 impedance ratio, while I need 1:2. Is it possible to change the ratio by including some resistors/inductors to match 100 Ohm output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are driving a 100 ohm transmission line that will work but it is going to cost you half of your power.

You would be far better off getting a 1:2 balun.

Answer (score 2):

Using reactive components, it is possible to match any arbitrary impedances *at a given frequency*. However, at *other* frequencies, the impedances will not match.

Generally, there is no power benefit accrued to matching impedances by adding a resistor, as the resistor will dissipate power.

The impedance ratio of a transformer type balun is the turns ratio *squared*. Since transformer type baluns generally have a small number of turns, the available impedance ratios are limited. An impedance ratio of 9:4 is not exactly 2:1 but it may be adequate for your use case. If it is not close enough, and you can live with more turns, impedance ratios of 16:9, and 49:25 are feasible.